# Git jumping back to history after adding and removing files has different behaviour?

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-add, git-rm

I'm a new comer to git. I found something interesting.

Say if I add a file and commit. After I checkout to the previous version, the file doesn't exist as I expected. (Since in the last commit, it hadn't been created)

However, if I remove a file and commit. After I jump back to the previous commit, the file doesn't exist as well, which surprises me.

Why there're different behaviours?

Thanks

**Edit:** Thanks for the reply. I jumped back to previous commits by git log showing the hash. And then git checkout 'hash'.

Comment: How are you 'jumping back to the previous commit'? Without knowing that, it's impossible to say definitively what is happening.

Comment: The behavior you are describing doesn't match anything I've seen with Git. How are you 'jumping' back to previous commits?

Comment: Which commands are you running?